# how can i convert InputStream to BufferInputStream in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

How can I convert InputStream to BufferInputStream in Kotlin?

```
fun ConvertStreamToString(inputStream:InputStream): String {

    val bufferreader=BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

    var line= String
    var AllString:String=""
    try {
        do {
            line=bufferreader.readLine()
            if (line!=null){
                AllString+=line
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `InputStream`, you can create a `BufferedInputStream` from it by using [`buffered`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/buffered.html) from the standard library:

```
val buffered: BufferedInputStream = inputStream.buffered()
```

If instead you want to create a `BufferedReader` (as in your code), you can use the [`bufferedReader`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/buffered-reader.html) extension.

```
val reader: BufferedReader = inputStream.bufferedReader()
```

And if you want to read all lines of a `BufferedReader`, you can do any of the following:

```
val lineList: List<String> = reader.readLines()

val lineSequence: Sequence<String> = reader.lineSequence()

val linesAsOneString: String = reader.lineSequence().joinToString("\n")
```

---

So, for example, you could implement your original function like this:

```
fun convertStreamToString(inputStream: InputStream) 
        = inputStream.bufferedReader().lineSequence().joinToString(separator = "")
```